# Генератор карт для пошаговой стратегии в unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Делаю `2D`-пошаговую стратегию, и для нее мне нужен генератор карт, который будет строить их по определенному алгоритму(например материк и острова с 3-мя видами местности, которые программа выбирает в зависимости от соседних клеток).

Я пробовал сделать это с помощью `tilemap`, но получился только рандом. Также я не понял можно ли хранить данные в тайлах. Еще я нашел вариант с созданием клонов префабов, на которые уже можно повесить скрипт и хранить там данные, однако я так и не нашел как создать не совсем рандомную карту(с теми же материками и островами). Смотрел примеры с использованием `PerlinNoise`, однако там выводили только точки.

Мой скрипт: [здесь](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19MjBJZFxu3L-y4Zbeq_COfYrgtncKxK2/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте создать несколько кусков материка как префаб, случайным образом их распределяйте, и остатки дорисуйте на основе соседних меток. Мне кажется выйдет неплохо

Comment: Задумка хорошая, но как избежать нескольких слоев префабов? (Пробовал через trigger, однако функция выполняется только для родительского объекта)

Comment: @Anton удалять по совпадению позиций